WPF + Python.NET Image (Graph) Loading Question
A.I would not use "Ironpython", but instead of that, I've tried to use "python.net" in my VS2O22
+Win 11 64bit+Python310 to load python graph (script.py) code to my C# wpf code like below.
# 10. Sphere plots (script.py => Added to my VS2022)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Make data
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

# Set an equal aspect ratio
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()

And this is my "pythonnet_test" C# code.
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //int dpi = 300;
            //BitmapSource bitmap;
            //Image image = new Image();
            Runtime.PythonDLL = "python310.dll";
            PythonEngine.Initialize();
           
                using (Py.GIL())
                {
                dynamic npi = Py.Import("numpy");
                dynamic mpl = Py.Import("matplotlib");
                mpl.use("TkAgg");

                dynamic plt = Py.Import("matplotlib.pyplot");
                //dynamic Axes3E = Py.Import("mpl_toolkits.mplot3d");
                //dynamic module1 = Py.Import("script");
                var fig = plt.figure();
                var ax = fig.add_subplot(plt.projection = "3d");

                //# Make data
                var u = npi.linspace(0, 2 * npi.pi, 100);
                var v = npi.linspace(0, npi.pi, 100);
                var x = 10 * npi.outer(npi.cos(u), npi.sin(v));
                var y = 10 * npi.outer(npi.sin(u), npi.sin(v));
                var z = 10 * npi.outer(npi.ones(npi.size(u)), npi.cos(v));

                //# Plot the surface
                ax.plot_surface(x, y, z);
                //# Set an equal aspect ratio
                ax.set_aspect("equal");
                plt.show();
                
                }
            PythonEngine.Shutdown();
        }
    }

And this is Mainwindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="pythonnet_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:pythonnet_test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Width="140"
            Content="Show Python Graph"
            Click="Button_Click"/>

            <Image x:Name="imgbox" Height="284" Width="450" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
           
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>

And this image is is my VS2022 solution explorer.
solution explorer
Q) How can I implement the '"pythonnet_test" C# code?
I want to display python graph via a C# WPF window, not via Console.Write.
3D Sphere
And the exception error was..
Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'Bbox.from_bounds() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'width' and 'height''
I don't understand what this means, and I can't find any relevant results on Google.
If you can recommend me better way except imagebox in "Mainwindow.xaml",
Welcome respond
(ie : Canvas, Textbox, ListView, DocumentView.....)

Maybe...
https://www.quantfns.com/integpython-net-matplotlib
The above source can help me but...
I don't know what's the difference between
//var pyfig = plt.subplots(figsize: new List { 1, 2, 3 });
//var pyfig = plt.plot(new List { 1, 2, 3 });
Actually, Shoul I add "fig, ax" for subplot or plot functions?

Is there anybody who can help this for me?
